# Angular file not found after deploy to server for route specific url

Tags: angular, url, angular-routing, angular-router

My angular app works perfectly on my localhost:4200. Now I have deploy it to the server. The [homepage](http://dev.fobo.live/) looks okay. It redirect to error page due to invalid URL. The valid url of the page is [this.](http://dev.fobo.live/1/3216549875/)

I get valid page if the [url](http://dev.fobo.live/1/3216549875/) has pass two route params in my local but for some reason it is not working on live server.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:":restaurantId/:mobileNo",
    component: LandingComponent,
  },
  {
    path:"",
    component: LandingComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]

  },
  {
    path:"error",
    component: ErrorComponent,
  },
];
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Freshii</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which command are u using for prod

Comment: i am using this for build `ng build --prod`

Comment: can you try with `ng build --prod --base-href="http://dev.fobo.live"`

Comment: still same error I get. No difference

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to access the url directly and you server does not have any information about this rout. This rout is only recognised by your angular app.
As i am not aware of your server configration now so i am not able to give you exact solution to fix it.
But if its an apache you can create an htaccess file and add the onfigration to first come at index.html before throwing an error

Comment: The files are hosted in AWS server.

Comment: If it is in S3 and you are using S3 bucket as a hosting directory you can add a .htaccess file there. I am adding code to my answer

Comment: its not s3. I think its normal ec2 . I just connect with my command and take pull and run build

Comment: you need to check how it is hosted with Aws. There are options to re-rout to index.html. Try to implement and it should get resolved

Comment: So the issues is not with my code right ? The issue is from server ?

Comment: Thanks the problem was with the server. We managed to fixed. I have posted the screenshot of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After this configuration made to this server ngix it is fix now.

[image: proxy and location configuration]